# How to write a code that automatically get the respodent's mail id using forms..(like google forms but not using it) ...?

Tags: php, html

In Google forms, we have an option collecting the `user_name` *(i.e mail id)* of the respondents.

What is the code for having the same feature but using other form developed using HTML, etc..

Comment: what you tried so far

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to ask them for it. There is no universal, automatic way to get a user's email address — it's only possible on Google Forms because the user is logged into Google with their account (which has an email address associated with it).